# No such module 'Facebook Login' with Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Working on Application with Facebook Login API. I'm currently just trying to get the Facebook Login Button on my viewController, but I keep getting this error:

> **No such module 'Facebook Login'**

It is next to my import statement: `import FacebookLogin`.

I installed CocoaPods and used a pod file to install the Facebook Files, just like the Facebook Developer SDK said to. I have tried a lot of options, but Swift just cannot seem to find my FacebookLogin module. All the kits are found but none of the .frameworks are.

I am using Xcode 9.

Comment: Are you opening your *.xcodeproj or *.xcworkspace? Because after you did install pods for the first time, you should have seen a message which says that you should use only *.xcworkspace from now on. Maybe that's the case. Or you configured your Podfile not properly.

Answer (score 2):

The module that handles Facebook login is called `FBSDKLoginKit`, so your import statement should say `import FBSDKLoginKit`.

Comment: Thanks. I should have guessed, but the documentation still says import FacebookLogin https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

Comment: confirm you must use: import FBSDKLoginKit